# Heroku dotnet core - libunwind.so.8: cannot open shared object - Common issue apparently

Tags: asp.net, heroku, .net-core

I created [this simple web app](https://github.com/amir734jj/milwaukee-internationals-dotnet/tree/fab47644bbbe40342f71f8b5e5e572dd2720b129) and I am trying to deploy it Heroku using [this build pack](https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack) but I get this exception:

> ```
> Failed to load �a�, error: libunwind.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Failed to bind to CoreCLR at '/home/ikriv/bin/dnc/libcoreclr.so'
> ```

Apparently, this is a common exception ([1](https://ikriv.com/blog/?p=2438), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3390), [3](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter/issues/118) and more). One solution I found out that looked promising was running: `sudo apt-get install libunwind8` but of course I don't have a sudo access nor can I run command on heroku. I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the code to use dotnet core 2.1 instead of 2.0 and apparently it solved the issue.

Comment: JS - You can make that comment an answer, since it worked for me too.

Comment: @purplecat I added the answer, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was changing the code (project `.csproj`) to use dotnet core 2.1 instead of 2.0 and it solved the issue.

So instead of:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I changed it to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```